# color the search result when the input is paragraph not a single line

Tags: bash, perl, awk, grep

I am trying to print the contents of the whole file with highlighted search string.

For a simple file where Record is equal to a single line then I can do this easily using:

```
grep --color=auto "myseacrchpattern" inputfile
```

Here my records are in form of paragraphs not single line. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( id SERIAL,
name varchar(20),
cost int );

CREATE TABLE notmytable ( id SERIAL,
name varchar(20),
cost int );
```

If I do use grep for keyword : "`notmytable`",it will give me colored output but only that line is printed.

```
grep --color=auto 'notmytable' inputfile
CREATE TABLE notmytable ( id SERIAL,  # <-- "notmytable" is in red but its not the whole query
```

I need something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE notmytable ( id SERIAL,   # <---"notmytable" is in red
name varchar(20),
cost int );
```

I can print the desired paragraph with awk or perl but how to color it :

```
awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' '/notmytable/' inputfile


CREATE TABLE notmytable ( id SERIAL,
name varchar(20),
cost int );
```

OR perl :

```
perl -00lne 'print $_ if /notmytable/' inputfile
CREATE TABLE notmytable ( id SERIAL,
name varchar(20),
cost int );
```

Comment: For Perl, see [Term::ANSIColor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor)

Comment: `perl -e 'use Term::ANSIColor; print color("red"), "Stop!\n", color("reset"); print color("green"), "Go!\n", color("reset");'`

Comment: In this particular case you can use the context control options of grep: `grep -A 2 notmytable input`

Comment: @Leon, I thought of it but could not use as number of lines are dynamic in real set of data.

Comment: @PS. You can build the print statement dynamically using this module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a string matching the desired regexp is found then surround it by the appropriate characters to change its color and print the record containing it:

```
$ awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' 'gsub(/notmytable/,"<RED>&</RED>")' file
CREATE TABLE <RED>notmytable</RED> ( id SERIAL,
name varchar(20),
cost int );
```

Just change `<RED>` and `</RED>` to the escape sequences for that color, e.g.

```
awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' 'gsub(/notmytable/,"\033[31m&\033[0m")' file
```

or if you don't want to hard-code those color values you could do:

```
awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' -v red="$(tput setaf 1)" -v nrm="$(tput sgr0)" 'gsub(/notmytable/,red"&"nrm)' file
```

BTW if you have blank lines between all records you'll probably find using `-v RS= -v ORS='\n\n'` works better for you than `-v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n'`.

Comment: excellent answer , tweaked a bit to make it work in real data. Although one question , why `gsub` is not inside `{...}`  ??  Dont we have to put action inside `{....}` ?

Comment: No, you don't have to put an action inside `{}` but just be aware that if you don't then it's result will be treated as a condition and so can cause a new action to occur, `print $0` by default, if it's result is `true`. In this case gsub() returns a count of the number of replacements it performed so I'm using it to perform replacements AND to trigger the default `print $0` action if it made any replacements. It's equivalent to writing `{ if (/foo/) { gsub(/foo/,bar); print $0 } }`

Answer (score 4):

```
perl "-MTerm::ANSIColor qw(:constants)" -00lnE'
    next if not /notmytable/; 
    for (split "\n") { /notmytable/ ? say RED $_, RESET : say }
' input
```

The `:constants` tag provides `RED` and such. There are other ways, see [Term::ANSIColor](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html)

Note that there has to be some duplicate searching, since we need to first identify the paragraph, but then print only that line in color while printing others normally.

---

If only the pattern need be colored, double-parsing isn't needed (and it's far easier and nicer)

```
perl -MTerm::ANSIColor -00lnE'say if s/(notmytable)/colored($1,"red")/eg' input
```

Comment: thanks, but this is coloring the whole para. Need to color just the matching string. my `perl` verison `This is perl, v5.10.1`

Comment: @PS. Right, it seemed that way but your perl example made me think otherwise.  That'd be too much for one-liner -- have to break the string (paragraph) into lines, match for coloring and for printing others ...

Comment: @PS. Alright, fixed it up ... feel free to put in a script :)

Comment: @PS. I realized that you may in fact want only the pattern colored, not that whole line.  This is easier, added to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Combine your `awk` or `perl` solution with `grep`:

```
perl -00lne 'print $_ if /notmytable/' input|grep -C1000 notmytable
```

The `-C1000` option makes `grep` keep 1000 lines of surrounding context around the matching line, actually turning `grep` into a mere colorizer rather than line selector.

You can wrap it into a bash function:

```
function paragrep() { perl -00lne 'print $_ if /'"$1"/ "$2"|grep -C1000 "$1"; }
```

Usage example:

```
$ paragrep notmytable input
CREATE TABLE notmytable ( id SERIAL,    # <---"notmytable" is in red
name varchar(20),
cost int );

$
```

Comment: or you can just use after perl `|grep --color '.*'` and whatever is printed by perl will be in color.